tsconfig not reading entry point of "types" suggesting due to pnpm
I am contributing to a web framework called Qwik, and I am new to contributing overall. Qwik requires contributors to the source code to use pnpm instead of npm.
The steps I did were the following:

outside of the root project (the source code), npm install -g pnpm
inside of the root project (the source code), pnpm install
I then did pnpm build.core See Qwik Contribution Guide

I came across a lot of errors on the 2nd part, but I just installed rust and some other random libraries and it ended up working. After I did the 3 steps, I realized everywhere throughout the source code, all the files do not recognize node_modules and therefore cannot import anything in the node_modules. I am wondering if tsconfig.json (which there is more than one as Qwik is a monorepo) has anything to do with the error I am receiving? Is there a step that I am missing? I'll provide details about my source code. and in case any further details are required, please comment.
OS SYSTEM: WSL using Ubuntu
tsconfig.json error:
Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptions
Cannot find type definition file for 'vite/client'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'vite/client' specified in compilerOptions

All errors in files:
Cannot find module LIBRARY or its corresponding type declarations.

I tried asking on Qwik's discord, but I haven't gotten any luck. I tried reading pnpm docs, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.
Any suggestions on what I can do for the source code to recognize node_modules would be great.
how my node_modules folder works in case anyone is interested.
enter image description here
